# vscode has correct python interpreter selected but it cannot see one of the installed modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed sympy using the commands

```
source website-env/bin/activate
(website-env)pip install sympy
```

My Python script is

```
import sympy as sp
u1,u2,d1,d2=sp.symbols('u1,u2,d1,d2')
psip,psim,phip,phim=sp.symbols('psip,psim,phip,phim')
psi=u1*(phip-phim)*u2-u1*(psip-psim)*d2-d1*(psip+psim)*u2+d1*(phip+phim)*d2
sp.factor(psi,phip,phim,psip,psim)
```

It runs fine from the command line but when I select this Python interpreter and try to run it within VSCode, it give "module not found - sympy"

My launch.json is

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you select the right environment? ctrl+shift+P then type select intepreter and hit return, then find your environment.

Comment: Yes I did; I could see the path clearly

Comment: How are you trying to run it, through terminal or something else?

Comment: Yes, it runs fine from the command line, either in terminal or from Linux

Comment: I run it from f5 in vscode; it fails there. I run it from terminal or command line and it succeeds

Comment: My guess is that there is a path issue somewhere. You could try changing type to python3 in the launch.json. If you print out sys.path in your script it will show where it's looking, hopefully your environment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was something wrong with my virtual environment. I used pip freeze to get a list of modules, then deleted the environment and recreated it. That fixed it.